# Fedora sshmenu problem

Tags: ssh, fedora

When I run sshmenu and try to connect to a ssh server I get

```
$SSH_AUTH_SOCK is not set. Is the ssh-agent running?
```

If I run `ssh-agent` I see the `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable.

How can I make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Running "`ssh-agent`" doesn't *set* any variables, because a process cannot modify the environment of any other process; so the program just outputs `sh`-compatible commands to stdout, intended to be `eval`'d.

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```